# Is "hidden by noise" a correct phrase?

Tags: single-word-requests, science

In a scientific article I want to say that the noise is large with respect to to the measurement that I am trying to preform. Specifically, I'm looking for peaks in some function, that may by "hidden" by noise.

Is "hidden by noise" the right expression, or is there a better word than "hidden"?

Comment: *Hidden* will deliver the message just fine. You can also consider *muffle* or *subdue*.

Comment: *Hidden* is fine as the context of whatever is hiding your objective is already apparent. You could also use *Masked* (Cambridge: concealed, disguised, not apparent, etc.). Cambridge lists this as AmE in origin but it's also in common usage in BrE.

Comment: Speaking as someone who has done a little bit of signal analysis, I would tend to say "obscured".  Though in some contexts a term such as "swamped" might be more appropriate.  Another term that might be appropriate, with minor rewording, is "buried".  A term such as "muffled" tends to imply the amplitude of the signal has been attenuated, vs the problem of being mixed with large-amplitude noise.  ("Masked" is pretty good.)

Comment: I believe "masked" is the accepted term.

Comment: "Drowned out" is fairly common in this type of usage.

Comment: What @michael.hor257k said. Google Books claims to have 151 written instances of [*(the) signal is **masked** by noise*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22signal+is+masked+by+noise%22), but only 8 for the same text with ***hidden***.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - could you write an answer, please?  I believe what you wrote in your comment is on target.

Comment: @aparente001 I am afraid I have nothing to support an answer except personal knowledge.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - You have the moral support of 5 upvotes to your comment, and you have the internet at your fingertips to find some support for this term.  How do we ever document our answers here?  We google on a hypothesis.

Comment: @aparente001 Feel free to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In a scientific article I want to say that the noise is large with respect to to the measurement that I am trying to perform. Specifically, I'm looking for peaks in some function, that may by "hidden" by noise.

The peaks may be *masked* by noise.

> [mask](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mask) (v. tr.): 2. b To make indistinct or difficult to perceive: *spices that mask the strong flavor of the meat; sounds that were masked by white noise.*

(American Heritage Dictionary, posted on thefreedictionary.com)